# Caching FileInfo properties in C#

Tags: c#, caching, .net, fileinfo

From the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo.name.aspx) for the `FileInfo.Name` property, I see that the data for the property is cached the first time it is called and will only be updated subsequently by using the `Refresh` method.

I've the following questions which I can't find or aren't too clear in the documentation:

1. Is the data for all properties cached at the same time?
2. Is the `Refresh` method called on creation of the `FileInfo`, or only when a property is called for the first time?
3. If I've called one property, e.g. the `Name` property, and it's called `Refresh`, will calling a different property, e.g. the `DirectoryName` property, for the first time cause it to call `Refresh` again, or is it only called by the first property accessed in the entire class (see question *#1*)?
4. Can I pre-cache all the properties by calling `Refresh` manually?  (Assuming it's not pre-cached on construction of the object)
5. Does calling `Refresh` manually cause properties which are [pre-cached](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesysteminfo.creationtime.aspx), e.g. `CreationTime`, to be refreshed as well?

Comment: I would suggest that you download ILSpy http://wiki.sharpdevelop.net/ILSpy.ashx and examine the implementation of FileInfo.  It is the best way to get answers to such detailed questions on the internals of BCL types.

Comment: I concur.  It's also worth noting that now (well, as in today now) you can browse the reference source online.  Here is the [FileInfo definition](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/fileinfo.cs,4ee673c1a4ecad41) in all it's glory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. At a guess, yes. It seems like a bit of a self-defeating "optimisation" for `FileInfo` to fetch only the properties you've fetched before, especially when they can be (and probably are) all fetched in [one API call](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364946%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).
2. The fact that the documentation calls out `DirectoryInfo` methods which serve up already-cached `FileInfo`s suggests quite strongly (to me, anyway) that simply constructing a `FileInfo` doesn't cache anything.  It makes sense - if you construct a `FileInfo` directly, it might refer to a file that doesn't exist yet (you plan to create it, for instance), whereas all the methods which return cached `FileInfo`s refer to files that exist at the time of the snapshot, under the assumption you're going to use at least *some* of them.
3. No, by my answer to question 1. That's why the Refresh method is there.
4. I would imagine so (see answer 1).
5. Yes. See answer 3.

Answer (score 2):

> The value of the CreationTime property is pre-cached if the current
>   instance of the FileSystemInfo object was returned from any of the
>   following DirectoryInfo methods:
>
> - GetDirectories
> - GetFiles
> - GetFileSystemInfos
> - EnumerateDirectories
> - EnumerateFiles
> - EnumerateFileSystemInfos
>
> To get the latest value, call the Refresh method.
>
> If the file described in the FileSystemInfo object does not exist,
>   this property will return 12:00 midnight, January 1, 1601 A.D. (C.E.)
>   Coordinated Universal Time (UTC), adjusted to local time.
>
> NTFS-formatted drives may cache file meta-info, such as file creation
>   time, for a short period of time. This process is known as file
>   tunneling. As a result, it may be necessary to explicitly set the
>   creation time of a file if you are overwriting or replacing an
>   existing file.

([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesysteminfo.creationtime.aspx))

Internally, `Refresh` calls the standard Win32API and thus fills all properties.

```
[...]
flag2 = Win32Native.GetFileAttributesEx(path, 0, ref data);
```

Accessing any property that is specified to Refresh causes a full refresh, for instance:

```
public DateTime LastAccessTimeUtc
{
    [SecuritySafeCritical]
    get
    {
        if (this._dataInitialised == -1)
        {
            this._data = default(Win32Native.WIN32_FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DATA);
            this.Refresh();
        }
        [...]
```